# Network Error Occur rollback metadata

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, networking, metadata, windows-forms-designer

Accessing Images from Network Directory and Writing Metadata on Images using Windows Form c# in a loop,If there is Network Error Occur then there is anyway to revert or rollback those images metadata blank as we roll back transaction in SQL,something like that.

Answer (score 1):

No. there is not, because the network does not support transactions. All data that is written up to that point is permanent, all data on it way may get lost.

If you need this kind of behaviour, may be you can build up a client-server scenario with transactions yourself. You could implement this with [Distributed Transactions](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Transaction_Coordinator).

Or, you could try to simulate some kind of 'transactionish' behaviour. You could store all changed images in a temporary folder, and when finish processing, simply move then to the destination. That will be fast.

Does that give an idea?